# How to place a tile by tapping on a isometric tiled map which uses CCLayerPanZoom class

Tags: xcode, dictionary, cocos2d-iphone, isometric

I have a tiled map. I use cocos2D. The isometric map has an CCLayerPanZoom. For Zooming and scrolling. Now I want to add a tile at the position where I pressed it. It does not work. It is inserting the tile at the wrong position.

Does it has to do with the scaling of the map(Zooming and Scroling which is posible).?

```
-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];   
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];



    CGPoint playerPos = _player.position;
    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation, playerPos);
    if (abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y)) {
        if (diff.x > 0) {
            playerPos.x += self.map.tileSize.width;
        } else {
            playerPos.x -= self.map.tileSize.width; 
        }    
    } else {
        if (diff.y > 0) {
            playerPos.y += self.map.tileSize.height;
        } else {
            playerPos.y -= self.map.tileSize.height;
        }
    }
    //player.position = playerPos; // Todo: Trymove

    if (playerPos.x <= (self.map.mapSize.width * self.map.tileSize.width) &&
        playerPos.y <= (self.map.mapSize.height * self.map.tileSize.height) &&
        playerPos.y >= 0 &&
        playerPos.x >= 0 ) {
        [self setPlayerPosition:playerPos];
    }

    if([TileMapLayer isOnTheMapMoreRestrictive:touchLocation map:self.map mapsize:self.map.mapSize.width] )
        [self plantObject:touchLocation];
    else
        CCLOG(@"Outside possition");

   [self setDotPosition: [self tilePosFromLocation:touchLocation tileMap:self.map]];

}



-(void)plantObject:(CGPoint) location{

    punkt = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"tree.png"];
    punkt. position = [self tilePosFromLocation:location tileMap:self.map];
    [_map  addChild:punkt z:4];
}
```